# icone no accordion bootstrap 4.0

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Boa tarde, agradeço a todos mas teria que ser em bootstrap 4.0, o site que estou inserindo é em wordpress e só tenho permissão na parte de editor html e css adicional.

1. Gostaria que toda a área da card fosse possível  clicar e abrir não só no titulo.
2. Não consegui adicionar icone a card alguem poderia me ajudar? gostaria que meu accordion ficasse que nem desse site: https://seama.es.gov.br/conselho-estadual-de-meio-ambiente

```
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row my-4">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="accordion">
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingOne">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"
                                aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                        data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                            squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                            quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                            squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                            craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                            butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                            nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingTwo">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                Collapsible Group Item #2
                            </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                            squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                            quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                            squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                            craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                            butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                            nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingThree">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree"
                        data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                            squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                            quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                            squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                            craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                            butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                            nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingThree">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFour" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                            squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                            quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                            squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                            craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                            butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                            nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingFive">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFive" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                            squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                            quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                            squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                            craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                            butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                            nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingSix">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseSix"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseSix" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingSix" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                            squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                            quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                            squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                            craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                            butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                            nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingSeven">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#collapseSeven" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseSeven" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingSeven"
                        data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                            squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                            quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                            squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                            craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                            butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                            nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha basta vc usar uma Font Icon qualquer como a `FontAwesome` para fazer os ícones, ai vc usa o próprio evento padrão de `Collaps` do Bootstrap para no CSS dizer quando mostrar um ícone ou outo. Quando vc clica no `Collapse` ele adiciona ou remove a classe `.collapsed` do `card-header` e com isso eu mostro ou escondo o ícone.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para deixar o elemento todo clicável baste ver tirar os atributos `id="headingOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"` do Button e colocar direto na `div class="card-header`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <style>
.card-header {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.card-header .fa-chevron-up{
    display: none;
}
.card-header.collapsed .fa-chevron-up{
    display: inline-block;
}
.card-header.collapsed .fa-chevron-down{
    display: none;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf
                moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda
                shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea
                proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim
                aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row my-4">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="accordion">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header p-0 collapsed d-flex align-items-center" id="headingOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"
                        aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link " >
                                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down ml-auto mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up ml-auto mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                            data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header p-0 collapsed d-flex align-items-center" id="headingTwo"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed">
                                    Collapsible Group Item #2
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down ml-auto mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up ml-auto mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="https://ap.imagensbrasil.org/images/2019/05/03/MARKETING.png"
                    alt="Deiliberações do ceca"
                    class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="https://ap.imagensbrasil.org/images/2019/05/03/MARKETING.png"
                    alt="Noticias do ceca"
                    class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Isso que você quer?

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="Accordion Bootstrap 4 with Expand Collapse Icon animation">
  <meta name="author" content="Arunkarthick Sunderavelu Rameshchandran">

  <title>Accordion Bootstrap 4</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CDN - CSS only -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Font Awesome CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp"
crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- User specific styles -->
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style> .accordion-head i{
font-size: 2.5em;
float: right;
}

.accordion-head > .collapsed > i:before{
content: "\f105";
}
</style>

</head>

<body id="page-top">


  <div class="container-fluid p-0">



<section class="p-3 p-lg-5 d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="my-auto">

    <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

      <!-- Accordion Item 1 -->
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="accordionHeadingOne">
          <div class="mb-0 row">
            <div class="col-12 no-padding accordion-head">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionBodyOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordionBodyOne"
                class="collapsed ">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h3>Accordion Item 1 - Heading</h3>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="accordionBodyOne" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="accordionHeadingOne" aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="card-block col-12">
            <p>Accordion Item 1 - Body</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin laoreet ante at nisi tempus, maximus bibendum
              odio consequat. Proin eleifend elit nec facilisis luctus. Donec ut ornare tellus. Proin posuere et leo
              vel congue. Nunc ipsum eros, vestibulum non mi et, porttitor tristique nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi
              tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum a turpis eu quam bibendum
              interdum a quis erat. Fusce porta odio sed nulla ultrices, gravida viverra nunc imperdiet.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Accordion Item 2 -->
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="accordionHeadingTwo">
          <div class="mb-0 row">
            <div class="col-12 no-padding accordion-head">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionBodyTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordionBodyTwo"
                class="collapsed ">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h3>Accordion Item 2 - Heading</h3>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="accordionBodyTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="accordionHeadingTwo" aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="card-block col-12">
            <p>Accordion Item 2 - Body</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin laoreet ante at nisi tempus, maximus bibendum
              odio consequat. Proin eleifend elit nec facilisis luctus. Donec ut ornare tellus. Proin posuere et leo
              vel congue. Nunc ipsum eros, vestibulum non mi et, porttitor tristique nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi
              tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum a turpis eu quam bibendum
              interdum a quis erat. Fusce porta odio sed nulla ultrices, gravida viverra nunc imperdiet.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Accordion Item 3 -->
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="accordionHeadingThree">
          <div class="mb-0 row">
            <div class="col-12 no-padding accordion-head">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionBodyThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordionBodyThree"
                class="collapsed ">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h3>Accordion Item 3 - Heading</h3>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="accordionBodyThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="accordionHeadingThree" aria-expanded="false">
          <div class="card-block col-12">
            <p>Accordion Item 3 - Body</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin laoreet ante at nisi tempus, maximus bibendum
              odio consequat. Proin eleifend elit nec facilisis luctus. Donec ut ornare tellus. Proin posuere et leo
              vel congue. Nunc ipsum eros, vestibulum non mi et, porttitor tristique nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi
              tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum a turpis eu quam bibendum
              interdum a quis erat. Fusce porta odio sed nulla ultrices, gravida viverra nunc imperdiet.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>
</section>



  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Lí sim, então são DUAS perguntas e eu respondi uma delas.

Comment: Ah sim, agora que editou me parece que ficou mais próximo, pq antes não tinha nada...

Comment: Boa tarde, obrigado por ajudar, mas teria que ser bootstrap 4.0 eu editei o topico, mil desculpas.

Comment: É bootstrap 4, olha o stylesheet