# Icone bootstrap 4.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-glyphicons

Tentei trocar somente as classe do icone e não deu certo, o que estou fazendo errado? E como mudar a cor quando eu abri a card

Pergunta anterior que abri
[icone no accordion bootstrap 4.0](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/381203/icone-no-accordion-bootstrap-4-0/381211#381211)

Obrigado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <style>

.card-header {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.card-header .fa-fa-plus{
    display: none;
}
.card-header.collapsed .fa-fa-plus{
    display: inline-block;
}
.card-header.collapsed .fa-fa-minus{
    display: none;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf
                moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda
                shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea
                proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim
                aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row my-4">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="accordion">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header p-0 collapsed d-flex align-items-center" id="headingOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"
                        aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link " >
                                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                           <i class="fa fa-minus ml-auto mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-plus ml-auto mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                            data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header p-0 collapsed d-flex align-items-center" id="headingTwo"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed">
                                    Collapsible Group Item #2
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                            <i class="fa fa-minus ml-auto mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-plus ml-auto mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="https://ap.imagensbrasil.org/images/2019/05/03/MARKETING.png"
                    alt="Deiliberações do ceca"
                    class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="https://ap.imagensbrasil.org/images/2019/05/03/MARKETING.png"
                    alt="Noticias do ceca"
                    class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

ExecutarVoltar para a publicação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa é a lista de classes para vc usar no FontAwesome, para começar vc escreveu a classe errado `.fa-fa-plus` deveria se `.fa.fa-plus` ou apenas `.fa-plus` https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/cheatsheet/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sobre trocar a cor vc pode usar o próprio `.collapsed` mais o `.fa` que precede todos os ícones para trocar a `color` *(já que FontAwesome é uma `fonte` normal como Arial)* quando aberto ou fechado, assim mesmo vc trocando de `fa fa-chevron-up` para `fa fa-plus` a troca de cor continua acontecendo `.card-header.collapsed .fa { color:red; }`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <style>

.card-header {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.card-header .fa-plus{
    display: none;
}
.card-header.collapsed .fa-plus{
    display: inline-block;
}
.card-header.collapsed .fa-minus{
    display: none;
}
.card-header.collapsed .fa{
    color:red;
}
.card-header .fa{
    color: blue;
}

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf
                moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda
                shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea
                proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim
                aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row my-4">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="accordion">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header p-0 collapsed d-flex align-items-center" id="headingOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"
                        aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link " >
                                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                           <i class="fa fa-minus ml-auto mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-plus ml-auto mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                            data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header p-0 collapsed d-flex align-items-center" id="headingTwo"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed">
                                    Collapsible Group Item #2
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                            <i class="fa fa-minus ml-auto mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-plus ml-auto mr-3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="https://ap.imagensbrasil.org/images/2019/05/03/MARKETING.png"
                    alt="Deiliberações do ceca"
                    class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="https://ap.imagensbrasil.org/images/2019/05/03/MARKETING.png"
                    alt="Noticias do ceca"
                    class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```